# Display Settings won't save: XRandR2 problem

Tags: display

I'm running SparkyLinux v5 Nibiru (Gameover Edition) on a Toshiba Laptop

I attached the HDMI port to an Insignia television.  When I tried to modify the settings, it gave me the following error:

GDBUS: Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.cinnamon.SettingsDaemon.XRANDR_2 was not provided by any .service files

I was able to get the secondary display working by restarting the machine, but not I cannot save the settings (in particular, I want to mirror displays).  It gives the same error.  Is there a config file I can edit manually or something I can do in terminal since the Display settings program doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Probably you removed that service in the autostart apps, like I did, however I cant find a solution to it.